# Is there any way (as a user) to force all notifications to be expandable?

Tags: notifications

Some notifications can't be read because they spill over the allotted space, but I can't expand them because the app developer never enabled that feature. Can I force all notifications on my phone to be expandable so I can read them?

Comment: If there is no expanded notification, then you can't expand it without manually changing the code (xposed might work but you need a custom module).

Comment: I wonder why the OS would be designed so as to make notification expandability an app level feature rather than a user level feature? Old apps might not be designed with this in mind, or they might be designed for a version of Android that didn't support expanded notifications - how hard would it be to allot extra space to display all the text?

Answer (score 3):

Provided that the notification itself has an expanded mode in the first place, Xposed framework + "All Notifications Expanded" module had done the trick for me back in KitKat, expanding every expandable item. Haven't tested it on Lollipop and above. Also, installing Xposed always involves some hassle and risk.

<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what I was asking for was not "automatically expand all notifications that I can already manually expand", but rather "enable all notifications to be expanded manually".