# How can you tell if a notification is expandable or not?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications

I've been loving the new expandable notifications ever since I discovered them by accident. However, I've just found out that according to the comments on this question: "[Is there any way (as a user) to force all notifications to be expandable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158105/is-there-any-way-as-a-user-to-force-all-notifications-to-be-expandable)", that whether a notification can be expanded or not varies by application.

Since expanding doesn't always work first time, but usually works depending on where your finger lands, how can I tell without trying to expand a notification 10 times if it's even possible to expand it in the first place?